# Two UIPickerViews and different combinations lead to different photos

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to swift Xcode and would like some help on UIPickerView.

I am trying to create two UIPickerViews, one called "From" and one called "To".  "From" contains A, B and "To" contains B, C

Basically, if "From" is A and "To" is B then a Photo of car will appear on the same viewController.
if "From" is B and "To" is B then a photo of strawberry will appear and so on.

Can anyone give me any hints on how to do this?  I've only managed to create the first UIPickerView.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var Picker1:UIPickerView!

    var Array = ["A","B","C"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

        Picker1.delegate = self
        Picker1.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return Array[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return Array.count
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {   
        return 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var savedVal1 = "" as String
var savedVal2 = "" as String
var array1 = NSArray()
var array2 = NSArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Picker1.delegate = self
    Picker1.dataSource = self
    Picker1.tag = 1

    Picker2.delegate = self
    Picker2.dataSource = self
    Picker2.tag = 2
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return array1[row]
    }
    else{
       return array2[row]
    }
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
       return array1.count
    }
    else{
       return array2.count
    }
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{

    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
        if pickerView.tag == 1 {
            savedVal1 = array1[row]
            // compare 2 values here & then take steps which fulfill your criteria.

        }
        else{
            savedVal2 = array2[row]
            //compare 2 values here & then take steps which fulfill your criteria.
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: do I still need to control-drag the two pickerviews to the script such that "@IBOutlet weak var Picker1: UIPickerView!" & "@IBOutlet weak var Picker2: UIPickerView!" appear?  Sorry i am very new to xcode so am a bit confused as to what the above script is actually doing.   Thanks SO much for your help, appreciate it.

Comment: Also how can I have two different arrays? for example, the first UIPickerView will have A, B and the second UIPickerView will have B, C?

Comment: No need to create two PickerView. You can create one & then Tag them for differentiate. And yes definitely you can use two different arrays. See my edited answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your PickerView2?

```
@IBOutlet var Picker2:UIPickerView!
```

In viewdidload load as you done

```
Picker1.delegate = self
Picker1.dataSource = self
```

If you are using same data source or different please check the picker view in UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource method like

```
 If (Picker1) {

} else if (Picker2) {

}
```